# Marginal Distribution Calculation of Discrete Random Vector

Tags: marginal-distribution, multinomial-distribution

[image]

In the question I know how to calculate marginal distribution for $X_1$ and $X_2$
Like for $X_1$ the marginal distribution for each column is the sum of each joint probability mass function in that column.
For example the marginal distribution for $0$ column of $X_1 = 0.343$
But I'm not able to understand how to use marginal Probability of $X_1$ in the binomial distribution as asked in the question in the image!

Comment: Have you calculated the marginal distribution in other situations? What formulas do you know in relation to the marginal distribution? Your question expends no effort in explaining this. Please do so, so that you can avoid downvotes and allow more users to access and answer your question better.

Comment: In the question I know how to calculate marginal distribution for X1 and X2 Like for X1 the marginal distribution for each column is the sum of each joint probability mass function in that column. For example the marginal distribution for 0 column of X1 = 0.343 But I'm not able to understand how to use marginal Probability of X1 in the binomial distribution as asked in the question in the image!

Comment: Much better.  I will edit your question to show you how to use MathJax. We can try to reopen this. I have done this : now, to your question. Imagine $(X_1,X_2)$ follows a multinomial distribution. Do you know the formula for specific values of $P(X_1= k , X_2 = l)$? For example what would be $P(X_1 = 3,X_2 = 0)$ as a formula? The way to solve the question is to relate those formulas to the numbers given, and then to find the values of the binomial parameters. Another point : do you know the Bayes' formula? This can be done from there as well.

Comment: First of all ThankYou for editing my question, I new to this so getting uesd to slowly slowly. By what I all knowledge I've for this topic P(X1 = 3) = 0.027 & P(X2 = 0) = 0.729.

Comment: Great, that's all you need , right? (Point : to write in MathJax just enclose your math in dollar signs like \$ a = b= c\$). If $X_1$ is binomial $(3,p)$ then the probability of $X_1 = 3$ is just $\binom{3}{0}p^3(1-p)^0 = p^3$, right? So you just need to find $p$ when $p^3 = 0.027$. Similarly for $X_2$. You will see that the answers are easy to find. The moral of the story is that all the knowledge you had was probably enough to do the question. The problem with the question you are doing is that you don't get marks for writing all the steps expect the last one, for example!

Comment: Okay so $X1~Bi(3,0.3)$ and $X2~Bi(3,0.1)$ will be the answer for my question? But why was $(1-p)^0$ taken because according to the formula shouldn't it be $(1-p)^(3-0)$ ?

Comment: Yes that will be the right answer. For $X_1 = 3$, we require $3$ successes, each happens with probability $p$, and zero failures, each happens with probability $1-p$. So that's why we get $p^3$ and $(1-p)^0$. If we have $X_1 = 0$ then we would have $p^0$ and $(1-p)^3$.

Comment: okay so what would happen if we had $X_1=1$ or $X_1=2$ ?

Comment: For $X_1 = 1$ we have one success and $2$ failures. So we get $p^1$ and $(1-p)^2$.Putting the binomial coefficient we have $P(X_1 = 1) = \binom{3}{1} p^1 (1-p)^2$ . In similar fashion $P(X_1 = 2) = \binom{3}{2} p^2 (1-p)^1$. All this follows from the general definition of the binomial.

Comment: Okay that was so helpful & I've improved my skills in MathJax by a little. Thank You so much for all your help.

Comment: You are welcome. If the question reopens then either call me to write an answer or write one yourself and call me to look at it. If you want me to see if any of your posts are good, or to edit posts, you can visit my chatroom, the link is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119549/teresa-lisbon-senior-agent-cbi) I have given you a +1 for your interest in the problem and for your interest in adapting MathJax. Remember, the better your question looks the more people will look at it!

Comment: Absolutely, I'll definitely let you know but when I click on your chatroom link It shows I must have a reputation of 20 to chat here. So therefore should I mention you in a comment if that is possible to contact you or is there any other possible way on stack exchange ?

Comment: You can go to that page when you have at least $20$ reputation (it just requires one more up vote on one of your questions or answers), otherwise you can come back to this page, and write @TeresaLisbon ... and I will get to see your comment. You can attach links of other questions of yours that you want me to look out for using this page. Thanks. (Actually, check your reputation now, it seems to have gone up)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank You so much

Comment: You are welcome, in general your questions are nice so keep going!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon the question opened & I answered it, I hope I answered it correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120413/discussion-between-teresa-lisbon-and-aishwin-tikku).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X_1$~$Bi(3,p)$
the probability for $X_1=3$ is $\binom{3}{0}p^3(1-p)^0 = p^3$ therefore
$p^3=0.027$ which will give $p=0.3$

$X_1 \sim Bi(3,0.3)$ is the answer & similarly we can find
$X_2 \sim Bi(3,0.1)$.

Comment: Great stuff, +1. Just remember one thing : your answer will not only be read by you, but also by others in the community. So some unmentioned points are also important. Write as much in complete English sentences as possible , and use MathJax as much as possible. These two will take you a long way. Of course, now you have the reputation to chat, so you may do so at the link I provide if you face any issues on the site. I will be of service to you. You can also accept your own answer after some time. (Small note : \sim gives $\sim$ like in $X \sim Y$).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank You so much again for this piece of advice & I will for sure chat with you for any doubts I have or face in stack Exchange

Comment: Sure, my pleasure in assisting you. I wish to do this for more people in the future.